# Problems getting results of MatchIt with rpy2 / How to debug R function with rpy2?

Tags: python, r, rpy2, matchit

I wasn't able to reproduce this in an MWE. I was using this code in the past and it worked. Some might have changed since then.

There is no error. The problem is that `get_balance` is of `NoneType`. The self build R function did not return something.

```
get_balance = robjects.r('''f <- function(match_out) {
        result <- summary(match_out)$sum.all
        result <- as.data.frame(result)
        return(result)
    }
    ''')

balance = get_balance(match_result)
```

I am not well experienced with R. So I don't know how to debug this or to add some debug helper lines in that R code.

I could break it into several steps e.g. `robjects.r['summary']`. But I don't know how to "translate" the `$sum.all` into Python.

I don't know where to start.

Comment: Please include all libraries. What type of object is `match_result`? This may need conversion from Python to R. R's `summary` dispatches differently depending on the class of object it runs on.

Answer (score 0):

The R code `f <- function() {}` does not return anything. It declares a function and binds it to the symbol `f` in the evaluation frame / environment.

You can either do:

```
get_balance = robjects.r('''function(match_out) {
    result <- summary(match_out)$sum.all
    result <- as.data.frame(result)
    return(result)
}
''')
```

or

```
get_balance = robjects.r('''f <- function(match_out) {
    result <- summary(match_out)$sum.all
    result <- as.data.frame(result)
    return(result)
}
f
''')
```